# How to compile executables in parallel

Tags: compilation, makefile

I need to compile 6144 executables. Doing them one after another serially is going to take a long time. How can I effectively parallelize the compilation? Each executable is compiled out of two files - the first containing the main program definition, and the second containing a few function definitions. The first file is common to all the executables. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Use  `make -j x` where `x` is the number of parallel build you want. The number of parallel builds should be no more than 1 or 2 more than the number of cores on your machine.

Comment: Thank you. Creating a makefile for this example is tedious too, as there are 6144 programs, each with a different set of object files. Perhaps a combination of scripts and makefiles would be easier?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I used a script to generate the Makefile, and used -j 24 to make (its a 12 core processor) and the compilation completed in 10 minutes.

Comment: You added the makefile tag which is why you got a make answer.

Comment: Got it. I was looking more for a script type answer, but currently make is working wonderfully and I am glad that I have an elegant way to quickly compile the whole set.